# Inverse gamma prior in rjags model

Tags: r, rjags

How do I specify the Inverse Gamma prior of (0.5, 0.5) in `rjags`?

I tried

```
prec ~ dgamma(1.0/2.0, 1.0/2.0)
tau <- sqrt(1/prec)
```

Not sure is this the right way to specify.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try making 3 different parameters (prec, sigma2, and tau (or sigma))?

```
sigma2 <- 1/prec
tau <- sqrt(sigma2)
```